# Same regex pattern, different results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I assume these two are equivalent:

```
let pattern1 = /\((.?)*\)/g;
let pattern2 = new RegExp('\((.?)*\)', 'g');
```

but they produce different results when applied on the following string:

```
let str = 'abc(a, b);'
let result1 = str.match(pattern1);
let result2 = str.match(pattern2);
```

Why?

Comment: Well, these are not the same. The second one is actually `'((.?)*)'`. You need to escape the `\\` otherwise it detects a escape sequence.

Comment: @MinusFour: Do you mean the escape character is extra?

Comment: @MinusFour: I am escaping the parenthesis

Comment: String literal notation will interpret the backslash for its own use, and so it does not result in a literal backslash that the regular expression needs.  It can be confusing, but both string literals and regular expressions use backslash as an escape character, so you need one for each phase: a double backslash

Comment: @MinusFour: That isn't what I want, you are wrong!

Comment: No, Arnold, you misunderstand their comment.

Comment: @trincot: That was a silly mistake of mine! you are correct and thanks for point out.

Comment: Basically, you need to double escape it. You escape the \ in the string so you actually get a \ character. Which is then used to escape the `(` in the regular expression.

Comment: @MinusFour: Yes, that's correct, I was distracted by the regex pattern itself. silly mistake